# Custom actionbar returns nullpointerexception in android

Tags: android

Hi Friends,
              I am using eclipse ADT. I am trying to display the custom actionbar. But its return nullpointer exception. Here the my logic i have return

```
`final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`
```

I am facing error nullpointer in setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD).. 
and my manifest file

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
```

This is my error reporting from the log

```
    08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.fragmenttabstutorial/com.androidbegin.fragmenttabstutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at com.androidbegin.fragmenttabstutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
08-14 16:14:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(10327):    ... 11 more
```

How can fix this error?

Comment: Post your stacktrace and point to the error.

Comment: `getActionBar()` returns `null` Change theme: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: then what about this.requestWindow(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: i have done android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: Mainactivity class is extending Activity or ActionbarActivity/ AppCompatActivity ??

Comment: If you want to use `ActionBar` then why are you using themes that has no title bar? change your theme